How to transition states of a specif amount of agents periodically in AnyLogic?
I am currently working on a simulation model in AnyLogic, where I have implemented a statechart with two states: "normal" and "active". The primary challenge I am facing is controlling the transition between these states. Specifically, I want the transitions to occur periodically for a specif amount of agents (at random) at a fixed time each day, precisely at midnight.
At present, I am using a rate transition, which causes the agents to transition between states over a period of time. However, this approach does not allow me to synchronize the transitions to happen exactly at midnight. Instead, the transitions are distributed over time, which does not align with my requirement.
Here is an image of the statechart for reference:
statechart for reference
I am using AnyLogic version 8.9.0 PLE on a Windows operating system. Despite searching for similar issues on StackOverflow and Google, I have not found any relevant solutions that address this specific problem.
There are no error messages or logs associated with this issue; the problem lies in how to effectively implement the periodic transitions at the desired time.
The impact of this issue is significant as the current setup causes transitions to happen gradually over time, rather than all at once at midnight, which is critical for the accuracy and functionality of my simulation model.
I am looking for guidance on how to achieve these periodic transitions at midnight. Is there a built-in method or a recommended approach in AnyLogic to implement such timed transitions?
I attempted to manually change the state using an event via coding within AnyLogic, but this method did not yield the desired outcome. It appears that implementing such timed transitions might not be straightforward using the conventional methods available in AnyLogic.

Use a cyclic event that triggers at midnight and make it loop through all your agents, randomly sending messages to some of them to trigger the transition

It might be a stupid question. But how do loop through all my agents?

Not stupid at  all. But pls always ask new questions in new issues on SOF. It is not a forum but a Q&A place. Also, try searching for such answers first, of course. We appreicate questions that show that you put some effort into it yourself :) Some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
